# converting enum variable to anyObject - ios with swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums

let me explain my code and then state the problem i'm facing

i have two viewControllers classes

1- difficultyViewController : where the user chooses the difficulty of the game

**difficultyViewController has three buttons for the user to click on which difficulty is desired

2- gameViewController : where the game will be presented to the user
**currently in the gameViewController only have a label

in the difficultyViewController i have an enum which represent the three game difficulties

```
class difficultyViewController: UIViewController {

    enum difficulties {
        case Easy
        case Medium
        case Hard
    }
     var gameDifficulty : difficulties?
    // other code is here
}
```

and in the gameViewController i have a variable correspond to this enum

```
class gameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var gameDifficultyLabel: UILabel!
    var gameDifficulty : difficultyViewController.difficulties?
    // other code is here
}
```

in the difficultyViewController i'm using code to perform and prepare for the segue

```
@IBAction func easyButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        gameDifficulty = .Easy
        performSegueWithIdentifier("toGame", sender: gameDifficulty as? AnyObject)
    }
```

and here is the prepare for segue code

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toGame" {
            if let gameVC = segue.destinationViewController as? gameViewController {
                if let difficulty = sender as? difficulties {
                    print(difficulty)
                    gameVC.gameDifficulty = difficulty
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and now the problem i'm facing is
when sending the difficulty as an argument to the perform segue, the conversion from the enum variable to the not valid and i always receive a nil value

what is the reason for that ? is it not possible to convert an enum to anyObject ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the game difficulty variable when the user presses the button, so why not just set the difficulty level based on that value?

Also, your class names and enum names should be capitalized to differentiate them from variable names.

```
class DifficultyViewController: UIViewController {

    enum Difficulties {
        case Easy
        case Medium
        case Hard
    }
     var gameDifficulty : Difficulties?
    // other code is here
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var gameDifficultyLabel: UILabel!
    var gameDifficulty : DifficultyViewController.Difficulties?
    // other code is here
} 


@IBAction func easyButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        gameDifficulty = .Easy
        performSegueWithIdentifier("toGame", sender: AnyObject)
}




override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toGame" {
            if let gameVC = segue.destinationViewController as? gameViewController {
                    gameVC.gameDifficulty = gameDifficulty // You changed this in the IBAction, so simply send it on to the next VC
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for you suggestion it worked perfectly. But do you have any idea why the conversion from enum to anyObject is not valid ?

Comment: I don't, and I'm ok with it :)